# Change user object to member object pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

So I have some code which needs to give someone the 'BANWATCHLIST' role, but the only ways to do this are with a member object, and all I have is a user object. Is there an easy way to do this like

```
dmchannel = await usrobj.create_dm()
await dmchannel.send(f"{user.mention} Be careful, you are now on the ban watch list!")

member = discord.Member(user.id)
await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(usrobj.guild.roles,name="BANWATCHLIST"))
```

I should mention I am not using the commands syntax

```
@client.command
async def example(ctx, *args):
    # Do stuff
```

So I have no `ctx` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If possible you will need to save the id of the guild you want to add the role too. You can then fetch the `discord.Member` object using [`discord.Guild.get_member` method](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member)

Also a few tips, don't use `create_dm` then send to the channel it returned, just do [`discord.User.send` method](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.User.send).

Also it is suggested that you get the role by it's ID using the [`discord.Guild.get_role` method](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) as it is more accurate and prevents getting other roles.